# When value is assigned to components state, why console.log prints the previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sending values of numbers from Numbers component to Main component. Everything is working fine until I set that value in my Main component to that  component's state.

```
var Numbers = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(number){
        this.props.num(number)
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, 1)}>1</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, 2)}>2</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, 3)}>3</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            number: 0
        }
    },
    handleCallback: function(num){
        console.log("number is right here: " + num);
        this.setState({
            number: num
        })
        console.log("but wrong here (previous number): " + this.state.number)
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Numbers num={this.handleCallback} />
            //<SomeComponent number={this.state.number} />
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Why is it behaving like this? Second `console.log` in `handleCallback` function prints the previous number, not the number which is in `num` parameter. I need right number to be in my state, because I'm going to send it immediately as an props in my `SomeComponent` component.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/13000/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you want to print the change after a call to `setState`, use the optional callback parameter:

```
this.setState({
    number: num
}, function () {
    console.log(this.state.number);
});
```

Comment: How would you solve out the problem with `SomeComponent` ? I now get why it isn't working, but I have no idea how I can pass the state as an props only when this.state has been updated. Can I somehow wrap that `<SomeComponent number={this.state.number} />}` to callback or something?

Comment: Changing a component's state or props forces a re-render, unless you have implemented `shouldComponentUpdate` to tell it otherwise.  Thus, once the state has changed in `<Main/>`, it will re-render, and pass the new number to `<SomeComponent/>` as a new prop.  If you have implemented `componentWillReceiveProps` in `<SomeComponent/>`, you will see the number in the received props.  Does this make sense?  Or would you like me to modify my answer and go a little more in depth?

Comment: You can go in depth if you have time / interest. I would myself really appreciate it. My problem with `<SomeComponent/>` is that it doesn't wait for `<Main/>`'s re-render (I believe..) so the right value from state isn't sent. I don't know how to implement that callback you showed for that. Maybe this explains a little bit better: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/13007/

Comment: Your problem is that you're alerting the current props in `<SomeComponent/>` instead of the new ones.  The function `componentWillReceiveProps` can take a parameter, `nextProps`, which contains all of the new props that were received.  Here's the fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/13008/.  Just remember that `this.props` does not change until `componentWillReceiveProps` has finished executing.

Answer (score 3):

The setState method is asynchronous, so the new state is not there yet on console.log call. You can pass a callback as a second parameter to setState and call console.log there. In this case the value will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the console.log is triggered before the new state has been really set.

You should use the function:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    console.log(this.state.number);
}
```

This function is triggered each time the state is updated.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the docs of the `setState` function is an interesting note:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to print state number in console use

```
this.setState({
        number: num
    },function(){console.log("but wrong here (previous number): " + this.state.number)})
```

instead of

```
this.setState({
        number: num
    })
    console.log("but wrong here (previous number): " + this.state.number)
```

In short: use `setState(function|object nextState[, function callback])`