# ReactJS style isn't applied and returned value is incorrect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The `console.log(handler)` returns handler value the first time executed instead of !handler

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Listitem(props) {
  const [handler, setHandler] = useState(true);

  function changeHandler(event) {
    setHandler(prev => !prev);

    console.log(handler);
  }
  return (
    <li
      onClick={changeHandler}
      style={{ textDecroration: !handler ? "line-through" : "none" }}
    >
      {props.text}
    </li>
  );
}
export default Listitem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in the CSS property. It's `textDecoration` not `textDecroration`.

And this is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702861/when-value-is-assigned-to-components-state-why-console-log-prints-the-previous) to your other `console.log` question.

From the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702861/when-value-is-assigned-to-components-state-why-console-log-prints-the-previous):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

**For Hooks,**

> Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side
>   effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with
>   `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(number);
  }, [number]);
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope this answers your question.