# React hooks not updating state for array of images on click event

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an image grid populated by a headless CMS in the background. When the user clicks on one of the images, they will be taken to an image slideshow.

I need to be able to open the image slideshow at the index of the clicked on image in the grid.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core";
import ImageSliderContent from "./ImageSliderContent";
import styles from "./LocationsImageGallery.module.css";
import ImageGrid from "./ImageGrid";
import ImageSlide from "./ImageSlide";
import Arrow from "./Arrow";
import Dots from "./Dots";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import client from "../../client";

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

const LocationsImageGallery = (props) => {
  const { caption, image } = props;

  const images = props.image;

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    translate: 0,
    transition: 0.45,
    activeSlide: 0,
  });

  const [showSlider, setShowSlider] = useState(false);
  const [showGrid, setShowGrid] = useState(true);

  const { translate, transition, activeSlide, _slides } = state;

  const size = useWindowSize();
  const transitionRef = useRef();

  function useWindowSize() {
    const isClient = typeof window === "object";

    function getSize() {
      return {
        width: isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined,
      };
    }

    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isClient) {
        return false;
      }

      function handleResize() {
        setWindowSize(getSize());
      }

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    return windowSize;
  }

  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (activeSlide === images.length - 1) {
      return setState({
        ...state,
        translate: 0,
        activeSlide: 0,
      });
    }

    setState({
      ...state,
      activeSlide: activeSlide + 1,
      translate: (activeSlide + 1) * size.width,
    });
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (activeSlide === 0) {
      return setState({
        ...state,
        translate: (images.length - 1) * size.width,
        activeSlide: images.length - 1,
      });
    }

    setState({
      ...state,
      activeSlide: activeSlide - 1,
      translate: (activeSlide - 1) * size.width,
    });
  };

  const show = (index) => {
    setShowGrid(false);
    setShowSlider(true);
    setState({ activeSlide: index });
    console.log(activeSlide, index, state);
  };

  const hide = () => {
    setShowSlider(false);
    setShowGrid(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <div className={styles.header}>
        <a href="/locations">X</a>
      </div>
      {showGrid && (
        <div className={styles.imageGrid}>
          <div className={styles.imageGridContainer}>
            {images.map((image, index, caption) => (
              <div className={styles.imageContainer} onClick={() => show(index)}>
                <img
                  src={builder.image(image).auto("format").width(2000).url()}
                  className={styles.image}
                  alt={image.caption}
                  key={index}
                />
                <p className={styles.caption}>{image.caption}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {showSlider && (
        <div className={styles.imageGalleryContainer}>
          <div className={styles.imageSlider}>
            <ImageSliderContent
              translate={translate}
              transition={transition}
              width={size.width * images.length}
            >
              {images.map((image, index, caption) => (
                <>
                  <ImageSlide
                    key={image + index}
                    content={builder.image(image).auto("format").url()}
                  ></ImageSlide>
                </>
              ))}
            </ImageSliderContent>
            <Arrow direction="left" handleClick={prevSlide} />
            <Arrow direction="right" handleClick={nextSlide} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.infoBar}>
            <p className={styles.infoCaption}>
              Locations / <span>{image.caption}</span>
            </p>
            <a href="" onClick={hide} className={styles.infoThumbnails}>
              Show Thumbnails
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LocationsImageGallery;
```

At the moment the active slide and index is both being passed to the function correctly. However the activeSlide in state doesn't update.

If I console.log(activeSlide, index, state), I get...

`0 5 {translate: 0, transition: 0.45, activeSlide: 0}`

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous so `console.log(activeSlide, index, state);` after `setState` wont always be what you think it'll be

Comment: Lots of code to read!!!! Please remove unimportant lines to be more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You have two (and maybe more) major bugs here, one is that you logging a stale state because [`setState` is async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702861/when-value-is-assigned-to-components-state-why-console-log-prints-the-previous).

Second is that `setState` of `useState` hook, don't merge state [like `this.setState` in classes](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged), so such code: `setState({ activeSlide: index });` will actually override your other state values: `{translate,activeSlide,...}`.

Usually, in such cases, you need to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
const show = (index) => {
  setShowGrid(false);
  setShowSlider(true);
  setState((prev) => {
    console.log(prev);
    return { ...prev, activeSlide: index };
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, still getting to grips with hooks. I can see how this is the correct approach for functional updates, however it still doesn't seem to be updating activeSlide. So my console.log reads as activeSlide: 0 no matter which index is clicked on.

Comment: You should make a reproducible example instead, such code is too long to figure out, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)