# Firebase data not saving to my react state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this block of code

```
class PaintingPage extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     paintings: []
   }
   this.database = this.database.bind(this);
 }

 database = () => {
   let db = fire.firestore();
   db.collection('PaintingProjects')
   .get()
   .then( snapshot => {
     let paintingData = [];
     snapshot.forEach( doc => {
       const data = doc.data()
       paintingData.push(data);
       console.log(paintingData, '1st')
       this.setState({
         paintings: paintingData,
       })
       console.log(this.paintings, '2nd')
     })
   })
 }

 componentWillMount(){
   this.database()
 }
```

I'm trying to save my PaintingProjects collection to my state. When I log the paintingData array all of my data is there but after I save it to my state and log my state its comes back as undefinied what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setState()` is an asynchronous operation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount` instead of willMount.

"componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render() , therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-render. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method"

Comment: I tried that unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(this.paintings, '2nd')` won't log the new state, but undefined, you should use this.state.paintings, but mind that it will log the previous state and not the new one.

You also shouldn't introduce side effects in componentWillMount. ComponentWillMount isn't awaited so your component will render without data at least once the same happens with componentDidMount though. But with componentDidMount, you can ensure that your componenet has support for an empty state.

Sources:

- [When value is assigned to components state, why console.log prints the previous state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702861/when-value-is-assigned-to-components-state-why-console-log-prints-the-previous#31703058)
- https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: `this.paintings` will always be undefined since it's, well, not defined. You must access the property inside of the state: `this.state.paintings`. That being said, it's definitely the old state when logged after a `setState` call since, like the duplicate points out, it's async.

Comment: True, I missed that. Been using function components for a few months now. Thanks.