# initialize state before rendering with parents props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-props

when i initialize my state

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          restaurant:this.props.restaurant
        }
    }
```

console.log(this.state.restaurant)
returns:
`[]`

"this.props.restaurant" contains data

i need to get the data from props (before rendering) to display them on a table otherwise my table will be empty

Comment: Setting state in react is not syncronous so console.log won't print updated value, try read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702861/when-value-is-assigned-to-components-state-why-console-log-prints-the-previous

Comment: not entirely, i need data from props (before rendering) to display them on a table otherwise my table will be empty (console.log is just for testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the React lifecycle docs: [Click Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

you can use the following code in your class to update before initial render:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    restaurant: null
  };
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.restaurant !== nextProps.restaurant) {
    return { restaurant: nextProps.restaurant };
  }

  return null;
}
```